# How to check if attribute is changing in update action in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

I'm trying to check - if some (language) attribute is changed and if it is equal to some value I need to change it into other proper value.

Here is my code:

**EDIT**:

```
    def update
@website = Website.find(params[:id])
@website.language = params[:website][:language]
if @website.language_changed?
  if params[:website][:language] == "Automatic (by user's browser language)"
    @website.language = full_language(request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first)
  end
end
respond_to do |format|
 if @website.save
   format.html { redirect_to @website, 
  notice: 'Note: code has been updated. Please replace the code you have on your website with the code below. Only then changes will take effect.' }
   end
  end
end
```

My form:

```
  <%= f.label "Website category"%>
  <%= f.select :category, options_for_select([
      "--- please select ---",
      "Banking",
      "Computers]) %>
  <%= f.label "Language preferences"%>
  <%= f.select :language, options_for_select([
       "--- please select ---",  
       "Automatic (by user's browser language)",
        "Arabic",
        "Chinese"]) %>
```

And when I'm changing category - it changint language to default. How can I prevent this ?

Gives me error:

```
   undefined method `updated?' for "--- please select ---":String
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: try `@website.changes` - return the hash, on the left is what was in object, on the right - what will be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tried this via the console, and it looks like ActiveRecord isn't tracking the change when you do a mass attribute update like `@website.attributes = params[:website]`.  It may be simpler to just do something like `if @website.language != params[:website][:language]` (and move your update somewhere later, of course.).  A little uglier, I realize, but it would work.  Of course, you can always look at enhancing your model to track changes from mass updates.

Regarding the fields changing - it sounds like your select list is not initializing to the correct values.  If the value of `@website.category` is "foo", then when this page loads the select list should have "foo" selected.  That doesn't seem to be happening, so when you submit the form and do your mass attribute update, its updating the category attribute to whatever list item was selected by default.

Comment: Thanks, @Scott how can I initialize selectBox with correct value ?

Comment: How can I change category and language separately ?

Comment: When you are doing `form_for` you should be able to be able to specify `form_for @website`, where @website is an object that was initialized in the action for this view.  If you're doing those things I would think the helpers would initialize the select list for you.  If not, check the docs for the rails select helper - you should be able to pass in the currently selected value to force it to initialize to that value.

Comment: You mean, make first option = @website.category ?

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that where you're calling your select helper you have `"Computers])` - there is no ending quote on the "Computers" value.  Is that just a typo in your post?

Answer (score 0):

`@website.language_changed?` is method,you can watch http://railscasts.com/episodes/109-tracking-attribute-changes

```
def update
  @website = Website.find(params[:id])

  if params[:website][:language] == "Automatic (by user's browser language)" &&  @website.language != params[:website][:language]
    params[:website][:language] = full_language(request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first)
  end
  if @website.update_attributes(params[:website])
  end

end
```

Comment: ok, thanks. But when I'm changing value in one select list the other field is changin.

Comment: other field is changing? i don't get it  might be you want only language field to be set `@website.language=params[:website][:language]`

Comment: I mean when I'm changing category - language is changing to default, when I'm changin language - category is changin too.

Comment: I want to make it stay the same until user is changing it.

Comment: so you don't want to change category while changing language if this is your case then `@website.attributes = params[:website]` use `@website.language=params[:website][:language]`

Comment: When I;m trying `if @website.language_updated?` started to give me `undefined method `language_updated?'`

Comment: it's not updated kindly refer answer it's `@website.language_changed?`

Comment: I will post code - and you will tell why it is continue to change, ok ?

Comment: as per your code and comment  i think you have change your question ,your initial question for updated? undefined method

Comment: Missunderstanding) When I'm changin ONE attribute - second is changing to ( into default selectbox value ) how can I prevent this ?